# How do I make an App Store in-app purchase notify my server?

Tags: server, app-store, notify, in-app

I expected to simply find a place that says "hit this URL with this data when an in-app purchase is successful," but I don't see anything like that at all in iTunes connect.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does now. Go to your app on iTunes Connect and under the "App Information" tab scroll down to "General Information" section and you will see a text field like this:

[image]

More info about it here:
[Subscription Status Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html)